# What is the extent of the import statement in Python

Tags: python

I have been getting different answers on the extent of the import statements in Python. I did some research on Stackoverflow to see what has been said on the topic. So if someone wants to import a python module from the current working directory, a file with a .py extension, then there should be no problem. However if someone wants to import a .py file from a different directory then there are two answers that are conflicting in my view (it maybe because i lack full understanding but I am trying to understand it):

First, this answer `[Importing files from different folder in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python)' which says that we cannot import files from different folders or directories in python.

Second, this answer `[How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)' which says that we can.

Can someone explain to me what is the difference?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: It says *by default* in the first answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing in Python is very simple:

1. Importing can only be done by referencing modules (not paths)
2. Python searches for things it can import in the following order:

   1. From the directory where the script was executed.
   2. From the directories in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable (if its set).
   3. From the system-wide Python installation's module directory.

It takes these three things and builds the `sys.path` list and searches it in the order listed. This has some basic problems. For example, if you have a directory with the following files:

```
foo.py
math.py
```

In `foo.py` if you say `import math` it will import things from `math.py` and not from the global `math` library that comes with Python. This is because the current directory is searched first for modules.

To import and use modules from a file system path which is not in the three places that Python searches, you need to add it to the `sys.path` variable, before you do any imports:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/some/directory/')
from somemodule import something
```

Answer (score 3):

Roughly speaking, the first example says that you cannot use the `import` statement to import from a specified location on disk.  The second example says that you can achieve a similar effect by using the `imp` module (which provides access to the internals of the import system).  So you can't "really" import such a module (in the sense that you can't use `import` to do it), but you can use the `imp` module to "make it work".

So if your question is about the `import` *statement*, then no, you can't (without a hack, see below); if your question about just "getting the module loaded" (without necessarily using the `import` statment), then yes you can.  It's sort of like saying "Can you *unlock* this door?  No, because you don't have the key.  Can you *open* this door?  Yes, by smashing it in with a sledgehammer."

Also, note that even the first example does provide a way to do it, it's just a bit of an ugly hack.

In practice, the real question is why you feel you need to do this.  It is rarely necessary and usually means you're creating a needlessly complicated library structure.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the answers are right. The first one uses a straight `import` statement, and indeed, you can't import from another folder that way.

The first one appends the path to `sys.path`, which is a list of directories python would search when you import a module. The second one doesn't use an `import` statement, but using `imp.load_source` which  works differently.

What would you want is usually either to put all of it in the same file, or make a script in a higher folder hierarchy which import all the needed files.

Answer (score 0):

Understand this:

> When importing a file, Python only searches the current directory,
>   the directory that the entry-point script is running from, and
>   sys.path which includes locations such as the package installation
>   directory

: Quoting from [Importing files from different folder in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python) 
Now lets say you have the files:

```
I) application/app/folder/file.py
II) application/app2/some_folder/some_file.py
```

You wish to import the functions from some_file.py to file.py. When you do `from application.app.folder.file import func_name`, python tries to resolve the path `application.app.folder.file`. It searches if there is a package/module named `application` in the current directory which is `application/app/folder/` for file.py and the directory paths in `sys.path`; and python fails to find `application` in any of the standard search paths. So **by default**, you can not import paths from some other folder that is not in the python path, **but** you can tell python about your custom search paths. You do this by adding your paths to the python path(`sys.path`)

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'application/app2/some_folder')

import some_file
```

If you want to import a file for which you know the absolute/full path (as in [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)), you do it as

```
import imp

foo = imp.load_source('module.name', '/path/to/file.py')
foo.MyClass()
```